# Cypress: How to move into specific time in videos?

Tags: cypress

I´m newbie with cypress and testing video and I would like to know how to move slider into specific time. I.e. my video is 30sec long so I tried this but this move slider into middle of video. What I m doing wrong? Thanks

```
cy.document().then(doc => {
  const progressElement = doc.querySelector(".progress");
  const oneSecondWidth = progressElement.offsetWidth / (durationS * 1);
  cy.log(progressElement.offsetWidth / (durationS * 1));
  cy.get(".progress").click(oneSecondWidth * 10, 0);
});
```

Comment: Could you add your error?

Comment: There is no error. Test passed, but slider of video was moved into middle not in defined oneSecondWidth. This was youtube video, and I want to move slider i.e. to 10 sec from beginnig. Thanks for any help or advice

Comment: Oh, in that case, nevermind